# Read a file for specific string and read lines after the match

Tags: string, awk

I have a file which looks like:

```
AA  
2   
3  
4  
CCC  
111  
222  
333  
XXX  
12  
23  
34
```

I am looking for awk command to search for a string 'CCC' from above and print all the lines that occur after 'CCC' but stop reading as soon as i reach 'XXX'.

A very simple command does the read for me but does not stop at XXX.

```
awk '$0 == "CCC" {i=1;next};i && i++' c.out
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

***Solution 1st:*** With `sed`.

```
sed -n '/CCC/,/XXX/p'  Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** With `awk`.

```
awk '/CCC/{flag=1} flag; /XXX/{flag=""}'  Input_file
```

***Solution 3rd:*** In case you want to print from string `CCC` to `XXX` but not these strings then do following.

```
awk '/CCC/{flag=1;next} /XXX/{flag=""} flag' Input_file
```

Comment: I would have thought `flag=0` would be the counterpart to `flag=1`, so I'm intrigued as to why `flag=""` which suddenly makes an integer into a string?

Comment: Also, if the script is supposed to stop reading, surely `flag=0; exit`?

Answer (score 1):

"Do something between this and that" can easily be solved with a [range pattern](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Ranges.html):

```
awk '/CCC/,/XXX/' # prints everything between CCC and XXX (inclusive)
```

But it's not exactly what you've asked. You wanted to print everything *after* `CCC` and *quit* (stop reading) on `XXX`. This translates to

```
awk '/XXX/{exit};f;/CCC/{f=1}'
```

Comment: The "normal awk-style solution" should never be used. Always use a flag. When you use a range expression it requires a complete rewrite or duplicate conditions whenever you have the tiniest changes in requirements (e.g. not printing the end of the range as is the case now).

Comment: @EdMorton OK, I'll rephrase that :-) But when requirements ever change on this all you do is 'rewrite' a no-brainer. (I use awk patterns most of the time only once anyway).

Comment: What people REALLY do though is rewrite it as `/CCC/,/XXX/{ if (!/XXX/) print}` as they want to build on what they have instead of scrap it and write it the right way with a flag and each condition listed just once. Then they have another requirements change and add onto the mess again. Seen it too many times. If you simply don't use range expressions then you can never fall into that trap.

Comment: @EdMorton What about `NR==2,NR==4`?

Comment: I wouldn't do it. I'd do `NR==2{f=1} f; NR==4{exit}'`. In addition to what I said previously that'd be much more efficient than `NR==2,NR==4` for any size of input file where efficiency matters.